# Java code to check the status of firewall

Tags: java, command, firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

I'm building a Java application to check to status of firewall. In simpler words,it should give the output whether the firewall is ON or OFF(note that when i say firewall ,i mean the built-in firewall that comes with Windows OS). I need this code to give the status of the local machine itself. Basically ,what i'm trying to do is simulate the command "netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no Java APIs for checking the built in Windows firewall status, so you will probably have to resort to executing a shell command from Java. An example:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state");
p.waitFor(); //Wait for the process to finish before continuing the Java program.

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  output.append(line + "\n");
}
//output.toString() will contain the result of "netsh advfirewall show all profiles state"
```

As I do not have a Windows machine at hand I do not know what `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state` returns but I imagine that a simple `output.toString().contains()` will work. Do not forget to catch any exceptions!

Comment: how to get firewall status in linux?